# Should I estimate varbinary maximum length, And How?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server database for our company's sales tracking.
It's become annoying since it has grown more than 10TB and it's still growing.

It's because of one table that stores sales recipes scan picture in `varbinary(max)` data-type.

Should I change varbinary maximum length for compressing data, And How?

Comment: The max size of varbinary without using MAX is 8000. I'll guess that your images are likely far larger. More importantly, the applications that use these images must be able to actually "use" them (presumably - otherwise why store them?) regardless of what path you choose. So what are those limitations? There is no tsql command that can convert between image types or change the compression level. It seems you need to do some additional research and have a discussion with your coworkers and the persons responsible for this system.

Comment: Nothing happened to the database size if you decrease field size. Size of the DB calculated base on what is stored inside. but it makes the batch scripts faster.

Answer (score 0):

I believe SMor and XAMT have given you the answer. 
Generally speaking, a 10TB database that keeps on growing will likely be unmanageable. So, you will need look at other options including archiving old data, then purging the archived data from the live database and shrinking it in a chunk. Also, you can look at storing the attachments in a file system and have the path to file in a database table (e.g., file stream).